# stop data being added with radio button highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

when i keep clicking the radio button it keeps adding a series when i dont want it to do that,

my code :

```
  $(".test").change(function() {
      var value = this.getAttribute("value");
      if (value == 'a') {
          chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
              text: "data"
          });
          if (chart.series.length >= 3) chart.series[1].remove();
          chart.addSeries({
              name: '2011',
              type: 'column',
              color: '#08F',
              data: [1, 0, 4]
          });
          chart.series[1].remove();
          chart.addSeries({
              name: '2012',
              type: 'column',
              color: '#808000',
              data: [8, 5, 3]
          });
          chart.addSeries({
              name: '2013',
              type: 'column',
              color: '#FFA500',
              data: [8, 1, 2]
          });
      }
```

radio buttons:

```
<input class="test" name="g" type="radio" value="a"> data</input>
<input class="test" name="g" type="radio" value="b"> data1</input>
<input class="test" name="g" type="radio" value="c"> data2</input>
```

the problem is when i click the a button, it keeps adding series

```
if (chart.series.length >= 3)
    chart.series[1].remove();
```

this is confusing me and i think is wrong.. i want the 3 data to show once when i click the a. however it keeps adding data...

in jfiddle, you can see that it keeps adding data when i click the buttons. when i only want it to show the data i have given each button..
     http://jsfiddle.net/Qkzx6/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if`s don't cover all chances: for example if you have B (chart with one series) and you press A, your first `if` will not fire (`length` isn't 2 or more) and your other `remove` with remove the 2nd series (`series` is zero-based); if you come from C (chart with two series) to A, your 1st `if` will remove the 2nd series again, then you add one more, then you remove the 2nd again, etc.

Just remove all the individual calls to `remove` inside each `if` and just put a `while` block before the first `if` that removes all series. Like this:

```
while (chart.series.length > 0) {
  chart.series[0].remove(true);
}
```

Your jsFiddle corrected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/VnCgx/).

Comment: by any chance do you no how i can add data to the x axis, "Jan", "Feb","Mar" etc..
i have the code
   xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }, but how will this fit into the jfiddle you edited

Comment: Just add it to the chart options when building the chart. Note that you are supplying 12 categories so you should supply 12 items in each series' data array. Check the updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/VnCgx/2/).

Comment: the problem is i want it diffrent for each chart, so for a it will be jan, feb, march etc.. whereas for b, it will be mon, tues, wed.. thats the problem..

Comment: Oh. You'll have to call `update` on the xAxis inside each `if` then. Pass it an object with the desired categories. Check it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/VnCgx/3/).

Comment: do you no how i can show the chart 'a' default when i first run the page, because at the moment i have no chart showing, as i have to click a radio button to show a chart, how do i show chart a as default when the page is loaded.http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/6/

Comment: Move the "A" code into a function and call it from the `if` and from the anonymous function body.

Comment: what are your resources that you use to learn about highcharts/javascript... u seem to no what you are talking about..

Comment: The Highcharts own documentation and demos are paramount to know how to use it. For js, I don't have a single source. Blog posts, articles, etc.